# Play Framework 2.6.x how to add a specific cookie to every request if the cookie does not exists

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'd like to add a specific cookie to all requests and results if the cookies does not exist.  I understand I could use the `withCookies` on the result, but I don't want to check every request in my controller methods and add it to every result.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaHttpFilters

Comment: @danielnixon I'm using action composition but I'm unable to get this to work.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ok I see filters are different from action composition.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: @danielnixon  that was it....thanks a billion!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles across this trying to use action composition it was easily achieved with a filter.

```
class MyCookieFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      requestHeader.cookies.get("myAwesomeCookie") match {
        case Some(cookie) => result.withCookies(cookie)
        case None => result.withCookies(Cookie("myAwesomeCookie",SecureRandomUtil.generateSecureRandom(255),Some(60*60*24*365)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example the filter is in the Controllers package.

In your application.conf file add this line in the play.filters section

`enabled += controllers.MyCookieFilter`

you would want to change controllers to whatever package you declared your filter in.